# Angular Controller Never called

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Im trying to use the Ionic Framework to create an app but i have problems to get a simple example to work. This is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- pouchdb -->
    <script src="lib/pouchdb/pouchdb.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

    <script src="js/modules/home.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controller/home.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="App">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>

</html>
```

My app.js

```
angular.module("App", ["ionic", "App.Home"])

.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state("app", {
        url: "/app",
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/app/home");
})

.run(function ($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {

        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }

        if (window.StatusBar) {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

My module home:

```
angular.module("App.Home", []) 

.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state("app.home", {
        url: "/home",
        views: {
            "main": {
                templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
                controller: "HomeController"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

As you can see here i want the `home.html` to use the `HomeController` So here is the `HomeController`

```
angular.module("App.Home")

.controller("HomeController", function() {
    console.log("controller");
});
```

But the home controller actually never is called. The logoutput never appears. My home.html is showing:

```
<ion-view view-title="Home">
    <ion-content>
        Home
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

I mapped the controller to the template so why isnt the controller method getting called?

**EDIT**

if i change my home.html to the following:

```
<ion-view view-title="Home">
    <ion-content ng-controller="HomeController">
        Home
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

It works. So setting `ng-controller="HomeController"` works fine but

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state("app.home", {
        url: "/home",
        templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
        controller: "HomeController"
    });
});
```

or

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state("app.home", {
        url: "/home",
        views: {
            "main": {
                templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
                controller: "HomeController"
            }
        }
    });
```

Does not work. For me that makes no sense. I want to use the stateProvider to set the controller.

**EDIT 2**

created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/e0Np3ZISBpf8oH8mdc7H?p=preview)

Comment: Any errors in your console?

Comment: no errors. no output at all. it seems everything is loading fine since the content of my home.html is showing. but the controller method of my "HomeController" is never called.

Comment: updated my post. if i set `ng-controller="HomeController"` in my home.html it works. But i want to use the stateProvider to set the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!

The controller gets instantiated when it gets bound to the view. 
I set the templateUrl of my abstract state to be `templates\home.html`
That is wrong. I just had to do:

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state("app", {
        url: "/app",
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: "",
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/app/home");
})
```

and to use:

```
angular.module("App.Home", []) 

.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state("app.home", {
        url: "/home",
        templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
        controller: "HomeController"
    });
});
```

So without to define views.